# Pass JS variable as a parameter in URLFOR

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, urlfor

I have the following code:

> URLFOR($Action[objectname].New, null,
>   [mode='autocomplete',suggestValue='"+queryTerm+"']), '')}"

queryTerm is a JS variable and I wanna pass it as a parameter for URLFOR.

Any ideas of how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly use JS in merge fields. URLFOR is built (merged) on the server, while JavaScript only makes sense in the context of a client.

Instead, you have to use JavaScript to modify the URL afterwards:

```
var url = '{!URLFOR($Action[objectname].New, null, mode='autocomplete',suggestValue='{value}'])}'.replace('{value}',queryTerm);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Sfdcfox, you can simply use following solution

```
var url = 'URLFOR($Action[objectname].New, null),'')}' + '?mode=autocomplete&suggestValue=' + queryTerm;
```